# Python y√x how to do this?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm not looking for the squared root. That is `numpy.sqrt()`. I'd like to figure out how to calculate y√x, where y is the nth root of x (I'm sorry I can't show it better). For example, say y is 3 and x is 64: 3√64 = 4. I'm not looking solely for the cube of x. I'm looking for nth, where n can be anything.

Thank you!

Comment: math.pow(base, 1/root). Example: math.pow(64, 1/3.0)

Answer (score 2):

The n-th root is the same as the (1/n)-th power.  So to find the n-th root of x, do `x**(1/n)`.  (Make sure to do `from __future__ import division` if using Python 2.)

Answer (score 1):

Using simple math

```
>>> a = 8
>>> a**(1./3.)
2.0
```

`3.` can be replaced with `nth` element.